# Use of object parameter type in Azure Devops template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline template in Azure DevOps which are used by many other pipelines. What I wanted to do is: based on a parameter pass by other pipelines, my template has to decide which k8s cluster the application deploy to.

From my below example, I wanted to find out the stageName from a predefined variable `$(System.StageName)` and based on the stage name I want to grab the k8s cluster details from the YAML parameter define with parameter name `clusters`, after that from the  `clusters` object I have to choose the cluster name based on one more parameter called `deployTo`

**pipeline/cd.yaml**

```
parameters:
- name: stageName
  type: string
  default: $(System.StageName)
- name: deployTo
  type: string
  default: all
- name: clusters
  type: object
  default:
    test:
        all:
        - test1.cluster.net
        - test2.cluster.net
        test1: test1.cluster.net
        test2: test2.cluster.net
    prod:
        all:
        - prod1.cluster.net
        - prod2.cluster.net
        prod1: test1.cluster.net
        prod2: test2.cluster.net

jobs:
- ${{ if eq('parameters.deployTo','all') }}:
  - ${{ each clsuter in parameters.clusters[parameters.stageName][parameters.deployTo] }}:
    - job: job_all
      steps:
      - bash:|
          echo do_something_with_${{ cluster }}

- ${{ if ne('parameters.deployTo','all') }}:
  - job: job_not_all
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo do_something_with ${{ parameters.clusters[parameters.stageName][parameters.deployTo] }}
```

**azure-pipeline.yaml**

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: test
  jobs:
  - template: pipeline/cd.yaml

- stage: prod
  jobs:
  - template: pipeline/cd.yaml
    parameters:
      deployTo: 'prod1'
```

From the above example:

1. I don't seem to fetch my expected value dynamically `parameters. clusters[parameters.stageName][parameters.deployTo]` - Is there any other way I can be able to fetch the value dynamically?

   If I just hardcode the value like `parameters.clusters.test.all[0]` or `parameters.clusters.test.test1` - It just work fine.
2. Wondering why this condition `${{ if eq('parameters.deployTo','all') }}` always get evaluated FALSE ?

Comment: in 2), it should be `${{ if eq(parameters.deployTo,'all') }}` (by wrapping parameters.deployTo in quotes you are literally comparing string "parameters.deployTo" with string "all").